# targeting nested foreach loop array in php

Tags: php

I want to foreach loop through the $tabs['downloads'] subarray element (see bottom of following snippet) within the parent foreach $content['tabs'] loop. My attempt is not working. I get an Invalid argument. Suggestions are appreciated.

Sample of $content array:

```
$content=
[tabs' => [
    0 => [
      'label' => 'Afoxé',
      'downloads' => [
            0 => 'afoxe2.mscz',
            1 => 'afoxe2.pdf'],
      'content' => "blah blah",
    ],
]
```

Nested foreach loop:

```
<? $i = 1; foreach($content['tabs'] as $key => $tab):
 $tabid=$tab['label'] . "-" . $tabsuffix; ?>
 <div class="tab-pane fade <?= ($i == 1 ? "show active" : "")?>" id="pills-<?=$tabid?>" role="tabpanel"
     aria-labelledby="pills-<?=$tabid?>-tab" tabindex="0">

     <?= $Parsedown->text($tab["content"]) ?>
   
     <? foreach($tab['downloads'] as $download): ?>
     <a class="btn btn-orange blob text-white" role="button" href="../public/<?= $download ?>"
         download="<?= $download ?>"><?= $download ?></a>
     <? endforeach; ?>
 </div>
 <? $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: please post the exact undefined index you are getting. I assume you are getting it for the `video` field

Comment: Do all your tabs have a `downloads` array? If not, add an `if` statement to check of `$tab['downloads']` exists before trying to loop over it.

Comment: Cornel Raiu the invalid argument is for the sub foreach loop. Barmar, all that tabs do temporarily all have the download subarray for testing, But I will add an if statement once I can get the foreach loop to work as likely only one tab out will have downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only undefined index I see in your code is the `video` field.

That is easily fixable with the use of the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). ***This only works with PHP 7+*** What it does is return its first operand if it exists and is not null; otherwise it returns its second operand.

As an alternative you can always use `if(isset($tab['video']))` before using the tested key anywhere else.

There is also the `$tabsuffix` but I will assume that is defined before the foreach.

However, if, for example, not all your entries have the `downloads` key, you should also handle that:

```
<? $i = 1; 
foreach($content['tabs'] as $key => $tab):
 $tabid=$tab['label'] . "-" . $tabsuffix; ?>
 <div class="tab-pane fade <?= ($i == 1 ? "show active" : "")?>" id="pills-<?=$tabid?>" role="tabpanel"
     aria-labelledby="pills-<?=$tabid?>-tab" tabindex="0">

     <? if( stripos(str_replace(' ', '', $tab['video'] ?? ''), '</iframe>' ) !== false )  : // <--- check this line ?>
     <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
         <?= $tab["video"] ?>
     </div>
     <? endif; ?>

     <?= $Parsedown->text($tab["content"]) ?>
   
     <? foreach($tab['downloads'] ?? [] as $download): // <--- and this line ?>
     <a class="btn btn-orange blob text-white" role="button" href="../public/<?= $download ?>"
         download="<?= $download ?>"><?= $download ?></a>
     <? endforeach; ?>
 </div>
 <? $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

You can see this code working [here](https://onlinephp.io?s=tVNtitswEP2dQO4wFQEl7Dre7I9CE3_Qc4RQZHtci2otYyuJszfqOXqxjqR47d0tlJY2YH3MPL15T5pEKSzmy1zXBmsTHxbzGTci6zjECdgd0O9hugHgSmSoHIJ_LnX_4zu_H5OFvtRKi2KkmI0kXBAeHzdPXf7sDvncdppripLf6GbHCfFNo6NlmRIV2IENiBfo9ndq4fF_6H0tgojPskDt61bGNN0uDC-VMHjGdtNfn_lfWHv8M2v_VoGbF_PjfjGnjpEQw3Zve8e2y6ksZU8R7lfcYUrdosir1dBdB99ZRxAdLL_h1dayp9c7IrcLWcR2Otx8HWEDLGA0jjX2kCaEjgp5hlyJrosZ5YJG1AilKBCiNIaVVUfyIAXWVfoCIjfyjAx2wNg6TRhQJdZIpbqA8L60DbdaoSO0fIp5zyBaKQInSWGRXX9xMqCZgd3UBfYxe2CJvQB3OkpBlivoTCsb3a1o_tJio0SOKw78Hjh93rV_riOkKQXXlIlCWbbiCRMOa_hAjkqhOqQ1GXHX4PgnV9EKIzW4Mdh-7D-xAeSFxL4Qc4XYccIREkkyCsa6kKW_ahccMy9v6hSP_x2n-uCfdoiupyrFoDEzNdAX6FbUX5HaTGdgsDfBpZIGhzfITsbomkHVYhmzzSZsTpmSeehMDAWInk0MDuGYvUMlbyNRKF77vRkb-mu4EEou5d3d_g3kJw%2C%2C&v=8.0.21). I have also added data with a `video` and one without the `downloads` key

Comment: I appreciate the added fallback to handle null array element s, as well as the working code example. Very detailed feedback.